# How Ogre uses STL containers in an exported class without C4251 warning?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, ogre

**OgrePrerequisites.h**

```
#define _OgreExport __declspec( dllexport )

template <typename K, typename V, typename P = std::less<K>, typename A = STLAllocator<std::pair<const K, V>, GeneralAllocPolicy> > 
struct map 
{ 
   typedef typename std::map<K, V, P, A> type;
   typedef typename std::map<K, V, P, A>::iterator iterator;
   typedef typename std::map<K, V, P, A>::const_iterator const_iterator;
}
```

**OgreLogManager.h**

```
class _OgreExport LogManager
{
protected:
    typedef map<String, Log*>::type LogList;
    /// A list of all the logs the manager can access
    LogList mLogs;
};
```

The `LogManager` use `std::map`, but when I built the project, I didn't get any C4251 warning:

```
**class 'std::map<_Kty,_Ty>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class**
```

I want to know how Ogre eliminates the `C4251` warning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They explicitly [disable](http://www.ogre3d.org/docs/api/1.9/_ogre_platform_8h_source.html#l00375) certain warnings with [#pragma warning](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c8f766e.aspx). As mentioned on MSDN, the usual approach is to disable warnings locally with combination of

```
#pragma warning( push )
#pragma warning( disable : 4705 )
// Some code
#pragma warning( pop )
```

To restore original warning settings. They restore warning settings in [OgreHeaderSuffix.h](http://www.ogre3d.org/docs/api/1.9/_ogre_header_suffix_8h_source.html#l00034), so these warnings are disabled for library code only.